# Calculating the norm of a bounded linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Then for any $g\in C[0,1]$ define the norm on $C[0,1]$ as $\|g\|=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|g(t)|$.

Then let $f:C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as 
$$
f(g)=\int_0^1 g(t)h(t)\,dt
$$
for some function $h\in L^1[0,1]$. Show that $f$ is a bounded linear functional and compute the norm of $f$.

MY ATTEMPT: Holder's inequality quickly establishes the fact that $f$ is a bounded linear functional since the max norm on $C[0,1]$ coincides with the $L^\infty$ norm on $C[0,1]$. If we let $\|f\|_*$ denote the norm of $f$ then we also get that $\|f\|_*\le \|h\|_1$ for all $g\in C[0,1]$.

I am certain that we actually have $\|f\|_*=\|h\|_1$ but I don't know how to turn the inequality around.

The usual trick is to find a function $g^*\in C[0,1]$ such that $f(g^*)=\|h\|_1$ which demonstrates that the upper bound is attainable for some function in $C[0,1]$. Unfortunately, the usual suspect for $g^*=\operatorname{sgn}(h)$ is not continuous. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g^*(x) = \operatorname{sgn} h(x)$. We see that $|g^*(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$,
and $\int h g^* = \|h\|_1$.

Since $h \in L^1[0,1]$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if
$m A < \delta$, then $\int_A |h| < \epsilon$.

Using Lusin's theorem (See Theorem 2.24 in Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis") for all $\delta>0$ we can find a continuous $c$ such that
$m \{x | c(x) \neq g^*(x) \} < \delta$ **and** $\sup_x |c(x)| \le \sup_x |g^*(x)|$.

Choose the $c$ above and let $A = \{x | c(x) \neq g^*(x) \}$, then
$|\int h g^* - \int h c| = |\int h (g^*-c)| = |\int_A h (g^*-c)| \le 2 \int_A |h| < 2 \epsilon$, which gives
$|f(c) - \|h\|_1| \le 2 \epsilon$. Since $\sup_x |c(x)| \le 1$, we see that
$\|c\| \le 1$ and $|f(c)|  \ge \|h\|_1- 2 \epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $\|f\|_* \ge \|h\|_1$.

As an aside, the bound is not necessarily achieved. A standard example is
to use $h = 1_{[0,{1 \over2})} - 1_{({1 \over2}, 1])}$. Then the corresponding
$f$ satisfies $\|f\|_* = 1$, but $f(c) <1$ for any $c$ with $\|c\| \le 1$.

Comment: How do you know for certain that $\text{sgn}(g)$ is continuous, and is therefore in $C\[0,1\]$?

Comment: I see! I had thought about using continuous approximations to $g^*$ but I was thinking it wouldn't work because I could end up with a limit function that was not continuous. I never need the limit function though, I simply pick the appropriate continuous function for any $\varepsilon>0$ and get close enough. Thanks!

Comment: @alonsos: $g*$ is not continuous in general, that is why we need to approximate it by $c$ above.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: I am guessing you were thinking of attaining the bound, but in general you can't...

Comment: Yes I was. The model I had in my textbook goes like this: If $h\in L^p$ and $L^q$ is the conjugate space, then $\|f\|_*\le\|h\|_p$ by Holder's inequality. But then $g^*=\|h\|_p^{1-p}\operatorname{sgn}(h)|h|^{p-1}\in L^q$ and  has the property that $f(g^*)=\|h\|_p$ and $\|g^*\|_q=1$. So when $p=1$ and $q=\infty$, then we have $g^*=\operatorname{sgn}(h)$. That is why I was looking at that specific function. Since continuity isn't an issue in the $L^p$ spaces, this is an appropriate choice, but not for $C[0,1]$

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: You had the right idea. The usual mnemonics are Littlewood's three principles (with suitable generalisations, for example, the fact that $\sup_x |c(x)| \le \sup_x |g^(x)|$ is very useful).

Comment: Thanks again! You have been a big help!

Comment: Delighted to be able to help.